# How to set a blob field to NULL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with a BLOB field that I sometimes want to set to NULL. If I edit a row in phpMyAdmin, I can set non-blob fields to NULL, but all I can do with a BLOB field is upload a file. If the field already has a value, the only way I have found to NULL it is to type in an SQL query. This makes each row update a two-step process, which makes it more error-prone (not to mention irritating).

I haven't found anything about this in the manual. If it makes a difference, I'm using phpMyAdmin version 3.3.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have been perplexed by the inability to set BLOB columns to NULL in phpMyAdmin. Luckily this seems to have been recently fixed: phpMyAdmin 3.4.1 happily lets you set BLOB columns to NULL.

Comment: That's good to know. I guess I'll just have to wait for my isp to upgrade the tools.